# Using nditer to sort values in arrays

Tags: python

I have two text files, each with the pixel intensities from an image. The first file I converted to a binary image by manually establishing a threshold:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as p

icp4 = np.loadtxt(icp4_img)
with np.nditer(icp4, op_flags=['readwrite']) as it:
    for x in it:
        if x[...] > 800:
            x[...] = 1
        else:
            x[...] = 0
p.imshow(icp4, interpolation='nearest', cmap='gray')
p.show()
print(icp4.shape)
>>>(45, 52)
```

With the second file, I want to sort the pixel values into two lists, which I will use to plot a histogram of pixel values, i.e. if the pixel is above threshold in the first array, then I want to sort it to the inside list.

```
#sorting pixels for PTM channel
ptm = np.loadtxt(ptm_img)

inside = [] #list for pixel values that colocalize with icp4 signal
outside = [] #list for pixel values that do not colocalize with icp4 signal

with np.nditer(ptm, op_flags=['readonly']) as it:
    i=0
    for x in it:
        if icp4[i] > 0:
            inside.append(x[...])
        else:
            outside.append(x[...])
        i+=1
sys.exit()
```

I cannot figure out how to reference the same position in array icp4 when iterating through the array ptm. I apologize if this is a duplicated question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as p

icp4 = np.loadtxt(icp4_img)
ptm = np.loadtxt(ptm_img)

inside, outside = [], []

with np.nditer(icp4, op_flags=['readwrite']) as icp_it, np.nditer(ptm, op_flags=['readonly']) as ptm_it:
    for icp, ptm in zip(icp_it, ptm_it):
        if icp[...] > 800:
            icp[...] = 1
        else:
            icp[...] = 0
        if np.all(icp > 0):
            inside.append(ptm)
        else:
            outside.append(ptm)

p.imshow(icp4, interpolation='nearest', cmap='gray')
p.show()
print(icp4.shape)

sys.exit()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This gives the following error: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Modified everything to happen in the same loop~

Comment: The lists are formatted like this: [array(435.), array(945.), array(761.), array(640.), array(597.), array(598.), array(1047.), array(702.)]